# Stylus define mixin via Javascript API

Tags: javascript, mixins, middleware, stylus

I have some functions defined via .define() like those:

```js
function sum(a,b){
 return new nodes.Unit((a + b), 'px')
}

//...

.define('sum', sum);
```

that works great I have access in my .styl files (e.g. `margin sum(10,5)`)

Now I am trying to pass a stylus mixin via javascript:

```js
function border(color){
 return "border: 1px solid" + color
}

//...

.define('border', border)
```

```css
div
  border(blue)
```

should compile to:

```
div
  border: 1px solid blue
```

Something like this  ..but suprisingly that doesnt work

You have any ideas?

I also tried to work with this but didnt know how to use exactly:

```js
style.define('border', new stylus.nodes.Function('border', 'color', 'border: 1px solid color'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just pass a string with stylus code to `define`, because Stylus doesn't know that it is a code (it coerces JS strings to Stylus strings automatically). You should parse this string, using `stylus.Parser`. For example:

```
var stylus = require('stylus'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    Parser = stylus.Parser,
    filename = 'test.styl';

stylus(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'))
    .set('filename', filename)
    .define('func', function() {
        var parser = new Parser('body { test: 1 + 1 }', { filename: filename });
        return parser.parse();
    }).render(function(err, css) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(css);
    });
```

But it's not so useful, because you cannot use vars defined in your stylus file in these functions. Basically the `define` is only for pure functions (not mixins that return stylus code).